# refresh the whole page and load a div on clicking a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
               $(window).load(function () {
                    var divs = $( #add_new, #details");    

                   $("li a").click(function () {
                        $(divs).hide();
                        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();
            });
            });

        <ul>
         <li><a class="add_new" href="javascript:void(0);"  >Add new</a></li>
        <li><a class="details" href="javascript:void(0);"  >details</a></li></ul>
        <div id="add_new">
        <p>ADD NEW</P>
    <input type="button" id="addsettings" value="Add Informations">
        </DIV>
        <div id="details">
        <p>detailssss</p>
        </div>

<script>
 $(function () {
        $("#addsettings").click(function () {

             $.ajax({
                    url: "manage.php",


                    success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results
                        $(".result").empty();
                        $(".result").show();
                        $(".result").append(html);
                    }
             });
        });
 });
 </script>
```

manage.php

```
<div id="div1">
pppppp
lll
kkk
</div>
<div id='div2'>
tttttt
gg
mm
</div>

<script>
$("#add_new").hide();
</script>
```

I need the page to get refreshed and then show the particular div tag. Now it is showing the div without page reload. For example, if i click the button inside add_new, it will take me to another page via ajax. In that another page, i have many divs (div1, div2) shown and I hide the `add_new` div here.  Then if I click the 'details' link, and then  go back to `add_new` again, it is still showing that divs which are in ajax page (div1, div2) not `add_new.

Please help me. I need the add_new div here.
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        var divs = $('#add_new,#details');    

            $("li a").click(function () {
            divs.css('display','none');

            $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).css('display','block');
        });
    });
</script>
<ul>
    <li><a class="add_new" href="javascript:void(0);"  >Add new</a></li>
    <li><a class="details" href="javascript:void(0);"  >details</a></li></ul>
<div id="add_new" style="display: none">
    <p>ADD NEW</P>
    <input type="button" id="addsettings" value="Add Informations">
</DIV>
<div id="details" style="display: none">
    <p>detailssss</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it is hiding the divs. But i need the page reload.

Comment: Nice one Maha, I like how you included the tag right at the start.

Comment: @athira what problems are you facing still?

Comment: when i click the button inside `add_new` i will be redirected to a page via ajax. On that page i had hidden the add_new div.  there i have 3 other divs shown.  Now when i click on `details` link it will show details div. Again when i click on `add_new` link it should show `add_new` div. But since i hide it on ajax page earlier that div is hidden and the divs which are in ajax page are show. The only way is to refresh the page. how can i do it?

Comment: You didn't tell the whole problem including ajax and redirection